# Arduino language shuffle order of an array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, random, arduino, shuffle

I'm working with arduino , but I can't seem to shuffle  an array.
the proplem is that with arduino I can't use an arraylist so hat makes it very hard for me to shuffle the array.

What I actually want is a list of numbers from 0 to 52 shuffled. so every time I run the program it is shuffled in a different order with the numbers from 0 to 52

Here is my code:

```
const int MAXNUMMER = 52;
int numbers[52];



int temp = numbers[first];
//int numbers[first] = numbers[second];
//int numbers[second] = temp;




 void setup() {
 // put your setup code here, to run once:
 Serial.begin(9600);

     randomizeList();
 }

 void loop() {
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

 }


 void randomizeList()
 {

 randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
 int r = random(53);


for(int i =0; i < MAXNUMMER; i++)
 {
  if(numbers[i] != r)

   {
  numbers[i] = r;

   Serial.println(numbers[i]);
   }

  }


  }
```

Comment: And your problem is ... what, exactly?

Comment: What I actually want is an list of numbers from 0 to 52 shuffled. so every time I run the program it is shuffled in a different order with the numbers from 0 to 52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and it should work. I just used the `Serial.print` in the function because I wanted to see all the at the end ;)

```
const int NUMOFNUMBERS = 52;
int numbers[NUMOFNUMBERS];

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  randomizeList();
}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

void randomizeList()
{
  unsigned char chosen[NUMOFNUMBERS];
  unsigned char index, i2;

  for (index = 0; index < NUMOFNUMBERS; index++)
    chosen[index] = 0;

  randomSeed(analogRead(A0));

  for (index = 0; index < NUMOFNUMBERS; index++)
  {
    int r = random(NUMOFNUMBERS-index);
    for (i2 = 0; i2 <= r; i2++)
    {
      r += chosen[i2];
    }
    chosen[r] = 1;
    numbers[index] = r;
    Serial.print(numbers[index]);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println("");
}
```

I changed the name of the variable from `MAXNUMMER` to `NUMOFNUMBERS` because it is the number of numbers to be generated (i.e. the maximum number will be `NUMOFNUMBERS - 1`

This is an example running this program for 6 times setting `NUMOFNUMBERS` to 5:

```
4 1 3 2 0 
2 3 4 0 1 
1 0 2 4 3 
0 4 1 3 2 
3 0 4 2 1 
4 3 2 1 0
```

EDIT: If you want to randomize the list more than once, I suggest you to move the `randomSeed` function from the function to the `setup` function. This way you will be able to call `randomizeList` every time you want.

One more thing: if you prefer to have a list with values [1,52] instead of [0,51] you can just edit the line `numbers[index] = r;` into `numbers[index] = r + 1;`